# Android application automatic update

Tags: android

I'm building an android app that is gonna be used by many users. So I'd like to know how the app can be automatically updated for all user as long as I'll be updating new version. How the application can automatically search for updates. 
Is there any tutorial link or explanation that can help in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your app will be used by many users you should publish it in Google Play Store using [Google Play Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console), using it you have the control of bug reports, installations and Crashes and ANR logs, the country of your user and more... But if you won't publish your app in Play Store you can follow some tutorials or add a text file on active URL where you compare the Application version with the Version wrote in the file, if the application version is oldest in another file write the link of the new version.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. I'm not sure I understood very well the second solution which consists of comparing two files. How does it work?

Comment: So, you can use a file (but you should download the file) or use a database, in file or database you write the version for example 1.0.0.2 and the link to download it.

Comment: Example: if the Application version is 1.0.0.0 and on file or database you find 1.0.0.2 the application download the new apk, you should convert all 4 digit and compare them.